# C# basic pre-emptive authentication

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, preemptive

I need to consume web service that requires basic pre-emptive authentication. I have below code, but getting an error on response -

> 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

User credentials are correct. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
string url = "MYURL";
HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

string user = "USER";
string pwd = "PASSWORD";


string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(user + ":" + pwd));
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
resp.Close();

req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);
resp.Close();
```

Comment: Do you have documentation? Authentication/Authorization takes many forms, how do you know it is using `Basic`? Modern services tend to use token authorization.

Comment: Documentation says: For REST (jSON) the basic authentication will be used.  This header would contain the WS-Security information.

Answer (score 2):

`401` is the error code you receive when you could not be authenticated (i.e. it's unclear *who you are*). If you get a `403` that means the server *knows who you are* but still thinks you should not be allowed access.

I guess you should talk to whoever provided you with the credentials and ask him.

Comment: Web service owners confirmed that user credentials are correct and we have access, but noted me that in case of REST I should use pre-emptive authentication, what I actually trying to do. We can also have an option to use SOAP. What is easier for newbies?

Comment: Did you check with a tool like Fiddler that you sent the correct header? Your code is weird, maybe it helps to post a [mcve]. Parts of your code should work, but it's hard to tell which parts you are actually running.